# Support for defining spring.json.key.type for each consumer binding in spring cloud stream bindings

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

After following the [JsonSerdeExample](https://github.com/schacko-samples/json-serde-example) I was able to directly consume the data from topics into my Java Objects. The following properties did all the magic

```
 spring.json.key.default.type: com.xxxx.datamapper.domain.FormUUID
 spring.json.value.default.type: com.xxxx.datamapper.domain.FormData
```

However, now I want to run two stream listeners in a single spring boot application. To do so I need a similar configuration for each consumer binding. Does spring cloud support this?

As of now for the second stream, I have to consume using String serializer and then do the mapping using Object mapper. This makes the application code convoluted with unnecessary transformation.

Answer (score 0):

That sample defines the Serdes at the binder level, you can also set them at the binding level

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.foo.consumer.key-serde=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.foo.consumer.value-serde=
```

To override the setting at the binder level.

Similarly, you can set properties for the Serdes the same way.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.foo.consumer.configuration.spring.json...
```

You can define the Serde at the binder level and properties at the binding level too.